# sqlite remove square meters symbol from column

Tags: sqlite, db-browser-sqlite

Let's say i have a column 'Sqr'

```
 39 м²
 48 м²
 50 м²
 15 м²
 38 м²
 38 м²
 35 м²
```

And I want to remove square meters so that my column will look like this:

```
 39 
 48 
 50 
 15 
 38 
 38 
 35
```

I've tried this query, but it didn't work

```
SELECT REPLACE(' 45 м²', ' м²', '');
```

How should my sqlite query look like?

Comment: What have you tried and why did it not work for you?

Comment: Works here. sqlite 3.28.0; sqlitebrower 3.11.2

Comment: @Adobe What's your definition of "works"? A `SELECT` does not alter Column content _in the db_ , right?

Comment: @Fildor: I run `SELECT REPLACE('45 м²', ' м²', '');` and it works: I get `45`.

Comment: @Adobe. Yes, it probably gives you a _result_ without m². But does it alter the table content?

Comment: @Fildor: Oh, I see. I though it was an issue with the unicode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that shows 3 ways :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (Sqr TEXT);
/*Option 1 */
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES('39 м²'),('48 м²'),('50 м²'),('15 м²'),('38 м²');
UPDATE mytable SET sqr = CAST(sqr AS INTEGER);
SELECT * FROM mytable;

/* Option 2 */
DELETE FROM mytable;
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES('39 м²'),('48 м²'),('50 м²'),('15 м²'),('38 м²');
UPDATE mytable SET sqr = replace(sqr,' м²','');
SELECT * FROM mytable;

/* Option 3 */
DELETE FROM mytable;
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES('39 м²'),('48 м²'),('50 м²'),('15 м²'),('38 м²');
UPDATE mytable SET sqr = substr(sqr,1,instr(sqr,' м²')-1);
SELECT * FROM mytable;
```

## Results :-

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Without regex replacement, the best you might be able to do would be a smart replace:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET Sqr = TRIM(REPLACE(Sqr, 'м²', ''));
```

This would remove the meters squared symbol in any context, and it also trims any dangling whitespace which might have been created by the removal.

Answer (score 1):

This query:

```
SELECT Sqr + 0 AS Sqr 
FROM tablename;
```

returns only the starting numeric part of the column, removing all chars starting from the 1st non numeric char.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dBbxxtF4RTVnN7Mx1aumiP/0).
If you want to update the table:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET Sqr = Sqr + 0;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dBbxxtF4RTVnN7Mx1aumiP/1).

Results:

```
| Sqr |
| --- |
| 39  |
| 48  |
| 50  |
| 15  |
| 38  |
| 38  |
| 35  |
```